# Reset Admin Password for JDeveloper - WebLogic Integrated server

Tags: java, weblogic, jdeveloper

I need to reset password of my web-logic server integrated with the jDeveloper 11. I have forgotten what I have given at the time of creation.

I am not able to edit or view it from the JDeveloper.
[image]
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to reset your integrated weblogic password.

When this occur, you need to delete your IntegratedWeblogic Domain and launch a new run.
Starting the new run will allow you to set a new weblogic account with a new password.

To delete your Integrated Weblogic Server you can do :

1. View Menu > Application Server Navigator > Application Servers > RightClick on IntegratedWeblogicServer and Delete
2. Another way is by manually deleting the default server folder in your windows path : 
   C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system11.1.2.3.39.62.76.1\DefaultDomain

Comment: Yes, this solution got worked for me. Deleting the domain folder is the only solution. Thanks